# How to catch conversation ending event?

Tags: node.js, botframework

Using Microsoft BotBuilder, I want to catch event when user close or terminate a conversation with my bot. Here is the code of my bot:

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

const inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
initialize(bot);

function initialize(bot) {
        bot.on('conversationUpdate', function(data) {

        });
    }
```

From the block of code above, I want to add an event that will handle ending conversation. Here is my example code:

```
function initialize(bot) {
        bot.on('conversationEnd', function(data) {
            var user = data.user,
                address = data.address,
                conversationId = data.address.conversation.id;
        });
    }
```

So, is there an event of ***conversationEnd*** like above code? I want to know if botBuilder can handle an ending conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event like `converstaionEnd`. Think of it in this way. If you are chatting with someone, you can just opt to not reply anymore. To a human user, it will seem that conversation has ended, but bot will not have any clue. It will keep on waiting. Unless you provide the intelligence to bot, to wait for a certain amount of time before considering that conversation has ended.

That said there are some other things you can handle:

- You can handle `conversationUpdate` event. This event is triggered when any member joins/leaves a converstaion. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events#greet-a-user-on-conversation-join)
- You can use a certain keyword (like *goodbye, exit*, etc.) as conversation ending keyword, which can trigger `endConversationAction`[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions#bind-an-endconversationaction)

Comment: Can we get user email from list of membersRemoved? From this loop:

`for (var i = 0; i < message.membersRemoved.length; i++) {
            if (message.membersRemoved[i].id === botId) {
                // Say goodbye
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                        .address(message.address)
                        .text("Goodbye");
                bot.send(reply);
                break;
            }
        }`

Can I get user email by this?

`var userEmail = message.membersRemoved[i].email;`

Comment: In general **No**. Not all the channel expose this data. Facebook might provide the username, but skype doesn't expose skypeId. Only User's public name (though I could be wrong). I don't think you should assume anything related to presence of user's email. Maybe if you could explain what you are trying to accomplish, we can find some whole other way to do it.